# Msmtprc SMTP with Office365

Tags: smtp, msmtp

I am configuring msmtprc smtp to send an outbound email and having a trouble with office365. It's working fine with Gmail account, but I am getting the following error with office 365.

`msmtp: authentication failed (method LOGIN)
msmtp: server message: 535 5.7.3 Authentication unsuccessful [BN6PR13CA0016.namprd13.prod.outlook.com]
msmtp: could not send mail (account default from /etc/msmtprc)`

/var/log/msmtp.log

`Authentication unsuccessful [BN6PR13CA0016.namprd13.prod.outlook.com]' errormsg='authentication failed (method LOGIN)' exitcode=EX_NOPERM`

/etc/msmtprc

`defaults
auth           on
logfile        /var/log/msmtp.log
account        office
host           smtp.office365.com
port           587
protocol       smtp
from           support@example.net
user           support@example.net
password       *******
tls            on
tls_starttls   on
tls_trust_file    /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt`

Does anyone successfully use Msmtprc with office365?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I've been successfully using msmtp fine for quite some time, using the following settings (on a CentOS 7 box), but with the config in `$HOME/.msmtprc` since it's just for my user rather than globally:

```
account          default
host             smtp.office365.com
port             587
tls              on
tls_starttls     on
tls_trust_file   /etc/ssl/certs/ca-bundle.crt
tls_certcheck    on
auth             on
user             username@example.com
passwordeval     pass office365.com
from             username@example.com
logfile          ~/.msmtp.d/msmtp.log
```

..so this is 99% the same as yours except that instead of having the password in the file I'm using `passwordeval` to provide it via the output of the given command.

Perhaps multiple spaces between `password` and the password itself is causing the spaces to be added to the start of the password?

You could also try running `msmtp` so that it has a controlling terminal (i.e. run from the shell rather than via the service manager as with `systemctl`) to test whether providing it the password that way works as expected?

Comment: Since posting this our O365 now requires OAUTH2, and I've been using `msmtp` pointed at `davmail` for sending mail as that's been the simplest way to support this (but it is very slow at sending sometimes).